# Sort text file per break line

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a highscore file for a minesweeper game I am creating and each time after it appends with the new scores, I want it to sort per break line.

I am using:

```
def save_score(score):
    name = input("type a name")
    file = open("highscores.txt", "a")
    file.write("Table: "+str(GRID_TILES)+"x"+str(GRID_TILES)+"\t mode:"+str(Dif)+"\t score:"+str(score)+"\t name:"+str(name)+"\n")
    file.close()
```

Which comes out in this format:

```
table: 10x10    mode: easy    score: 7592    name:Test
table: 5x5      mode: medium  score: 2707    name:Test
```

How can I make it so that after either the `file.write` or the `file.close` it sorts the file per line?

I want it to be sorted by table only. It doesn't matter in what order, as long as all the tables that are 7x7 go by those that are also 7x7.

I have tried doing this:

```
def save_score(score):
    name = input("type a name")
    file = open("highscores.txt", "a")
    file.write("table: "+str(GRID_TILES)+"x"+str(GRID_TILES)+"\t mode: "+str(Dif) +"\t score: "+str(score)+"\t name: "+str(name)+"\n")
    file.close()
    file = open("scores.txt", "r")
    file2 = open("highscores.txt", "w")
    file2.writelines(sorted(file, key=lambda line:str(line.split()[0])))
    file.close()
    file2.close()
```

I want to keep my code as short as possible, as the entire minesweeper will take up quite some ammount of code.

Comment: Perhaps you can provide an example of your expected output.

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm not native to the English language, can you explain that any further?

Comment: Can you show an example of what the file looks like after the sorting that you want.

Comment: you have to read all lines to memory, sort it, and write all lines to file again.

Comment: Your attempt looks sensible, except that instead of `[0]` you maybe meant `[1]` unless you intend to sort all lines on the first word of the line, which is always just `table:`.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way:

```
import shutil
from tempfile import NamedTemporaryFile


def insert_sorted(file_obj, in_line):
    flag = False
    with NamedTemporaryFile(delete=False, mode="w+") as temp:
        try:
            val = int(in_line.split()[-2])
        except (IndexError, ValueError):
            raise Exception("Invalid format")

        for line in file_obj:
            try:
                lineval = int(line.split()[-2])
            except (IndexError, ValueError):
                print("""following line has an invalid format,\
                and gets escaped\n{}""".format(line))
            else:
                # Write larger score first when we find smaller score
                if lineval <= val:
                    temp.write(in_line)
                    temp.write(line)
                    flag = True
                    break
                else:
                    temp.write(line)

        for line in file_obj:
            temp.write(line)
        # if the score of the in_line is grater than all the lines write it at the trailing.
        if not flag:
            temp.write(in_line)
    return temp

with open(file_name) as f:
    in_line = "table: 10x10    mode: easy    score: 8592    name:Test"
    temp = insert_sorted(f, in_line)
    shutil.move(temp.name, file_name)
```

Comment: Given this is Python 3, you want to explicitly open `NamedTemporaryFile` in text mode (`mode="w+"`). Otherwise, you're reading `str` from the original file, and trying to write `str` to a binary mode `NamedTemporaryFile` that only accepts `bytes`. Also, you forgot to write `in_line` at all.

Comment: @ShadowRanger Good catch! thanks for note, just fixed.

Comment: You still had an issue (none of the scores higher than the new score were being written). I edited, double-check me please.

Comment: BTW, minor improvement that could be made to reduce work: If the file name is known, pass `dir=os.path.dirname(file_obj.name)` to the `NamedTemporaryFile` constructor. This will put the temporary file in the same directory that it will be moved to, so the final `move` will likely be an atomic rename, not a copy-and-delete operation.

Comment: @ShadowRanger Thanks, but your edit has some problems now, first off you should write the `in_line` if the value is less and equal with the current line's value, secondly you have an extra comparison (`lineval < val`)

Comment: @ShadowRanger Regarding the performance improvement, that'd be a good idea but I think there are a lot of improvements that you can apply on this code in order to make it better, but its not what the OP is looking for now. So basically it's better to don't confuse the user with extra improvement.

Comment: I made the test `<` rather than `<=` to put a new equal score after any identical scores, rather than ahead (this is personal preference, but usually, unseating the current holder of a record requires beating the record, not just matching it, so using `<` puts the newer score lower than older equal scores; also, implementation detail, but Python's sorting uses `<` exclusively, so this matches that behavior). Looks like they didn't want score sorting anyway though. Double test is admittedly sub-optimal; trying to stick to DRY is hard; you either repeat the test or repeat the `write` call.

Comment: @ShadowRanger Your code would never write the `in-line` if the score was equal or even larger for all the lines. Also, I never repeated the `write` call, the second one runs in `else` clause.

Answer (score 0):

```
def save_score(score):
    name = input("type a name")
    with open("scores.txt", "a") as file:
        file.write("table: {}x{}\t mode: {}\t score: {}\t name: {}\n".format(
                   GRID_TILES, GRID_TILES, Dif, score, name))

    with open("scores.txt") as file, open("highscores.txt", "w") as file2:
        file2.writelines(sorted(file, key=lambda line: line.split()[1]))
```

Thanks to Frerich Raabe for supplying me with an answer!

Comment: I made some major cleanups on this (only functional difference is that using `with` statements means files are guaranteed to be closed implicitly at end of `with` block, even in the presence of exceptions). Feel free to roll it back, but this is _much_ more Pythonic/readable, and even more concise (because no `.close()` calls are needed). One note: Surely the file being opened for append should be `scores.txt`? Otherwise, you append a new line to `highscores.txt`, then immediately blow it away, replacing it with the sorted contents of the `scores.txt`.

Comment: @ShadowRanger I'm afraid I have to change the code back, as this updated version doesn't seem to work. And yes, you are more then right on the `highscores.txt` part being appended. I have corrected that mistake.

Comment: Doesn't seem to work? OOC, what breaks? I'd _strongly_ recommend using `with` statements, if nothing else; otherwise you end up in a position of accidentally forgetting to close files, or even if you remember, having the `close` call bypassed when an exception occurs.

Comment: It doesn't paste any of the data to any of the files, I've tested it multiple times, yet neither `scores.txt` nor `highscores.txt` get updated, even when closing and reopening the file. (not in the code, just regular opening and closing.)

Comment: @ShadowRanger I'd love to improve the code, but I both have a deadline and I have more important parts of the project. Whenever I am done with the more important parts, I'll get to code testing, where I'll try and give the code a fixer-upper.

Comment: Okay, but I suspect the problem is that the edit I made (which as I said, was not intended to change success case behaviors) still used `highscores.txt` as the target for the append (which meant it suffered the same bug where the append was immediately undone because `highscores.txt` was overwritten with the sorted contents of the untouched `scores.txt`). I didn't want to change the meaning of the code, which is why I saved that note for a comment.

Comment: @ShadowRanger thank you, it worked